# How to bind same window as a Data Context?

Tags: wpf

I have maintains the collection for the Combo-Box in Window code behind, if I bound that collection via xaml means it’s unable to fetch the collection until externally set the DataContext for the window in code behind. can anyone help me to resolve this.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Orders
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {         
            InitializeComponent();
            Orders = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Orders.Add("1000");
            Orders.Add("1001");
            Orders.Add("1002");
            Orders.Add("1003");
            //this.DataContext = this;
        }
```

Comment: `DataContext = this;` would be correct. You seem to have it already.

Comment: Yep, I already changed the comment. I can't work out what he means.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Binding to a collection of strings can have some odd effects maybe that's related to what he's seeing. I'd rather see that collection in a separate viewmodel as well.... But I think we need some explanation.

Comment: @Andy *"Binding to a collection of strings can have some odd effects"*  What? That makes absolutely no sense, sorry. With `DataContext = this;` any binding to the Orders property would just work.

Comment: It is of course not strictly *necessary* to set the Window's DataContext to itself in order to be able to bind to its own property. A Binding like `{Binding Orders, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}` should also work.

Comment: And you could bind datacontext. I was wondering what he's seeing that isn't working.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your quick response its working well and good

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
        <ComboBox Height="25" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"></ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

You can set the DataContext for the Grid itself to use the same in various UI elements

Answer (score 0):

You can bind datacontext of the window to itself.
That still will not work unless you move setting up the data though:

```
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        >
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and

```
   public ObservableCollection<string> Orders
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Orders = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Orders.Add("1000");
        Orders.Add("1001");
        Orders.Add("1002");
        Orders.Add("1003");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```